# Capturing SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in script for initiating SFTP session in OpenSSH for Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, batch, openssh, sftp

I'd like to execute a script on `Windows OpenSSH server`, and then allow the execution of whatever original command was issued (most likely`SFTP`). On `Linux`, it just involves using the `ForceCommand` directive in`sshd_config` to run `.sh`, and using the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable passed to the script to be executed using `sh -c`.

**sshd_config**

```
<rest of it>
Match user <someuser>
ForceCommand <somescript>.sh
```

**somescript.sh**

```
sh -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

On `Windows OpenSSH` Server however, I am not sure how this should be run. I imagine I can run some batch script in `ForceCommand` but I am not sure how the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` can be captured and executed from within the script.

I have looked online, but haven't come across any such example. Is this supported on Windows OpenSSH, and if so, how can I go about it?

**UPDATE -**

I have tried with "%SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND%", but calling the script as :

**sshd_config**

```
Match user <someuser>
ForceCommand <-Accesible_Directry->/testscript.bat
```

and

**testscript.bat**

```
start %SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND%
```

with or without quotes does not seem to work. There may be a syntax issue in calling this somewhere, either in `sshd_config` or in the `batch` file. `WinSCP` reports that too large a `SFTP` packet was received.

**UPDATE 2**

I made the batch script as -

```
@echo off
%SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND%
```

This works for `SFTP`, a session gets initiated, but a `SSH` connection terminates, if that was the intended use. If I understand it correctly, connecting via `ssh` is itself what gets initiated, which then executes the script, `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` I assume is blank, since it was a `ssh` connection, according to https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/737, so the batch script terminates, and session ends. Is this understading accurate?

Comment: *"`SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` I assume is blank"* – I believe so. It's easy to test. Why don't you try?

Comment: Yes, it is blank. Original command in case of `SFTP` is `sftp-server.exe`, while it is blank when I initiate a `ssh` session. In this scenario, if I'd wanted a SSH connection to be established post execution of some script based stuff, that would mean checking if blank command was received and launching a shell like cmd from script?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.